# Method to Change Word

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a program that changes the current word in HTML into a new word using a function in JavaScript. I try to create a method inside the function in JavaScript that will change the word into another word after 1 second. This is my coding that I attempt to try :

HTML

```
<html>

<body>
    <div id="demo">
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some other text</p>
    </div>
    <script src="style.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```js
let x, a, arr, i;

function setText() {
    a = document.getElementById("demo");
    arr = a.childNodes;
    for (x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        arr[x].innerHTML = "new text";
    }
    this.r = revert;
}
function revert() {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i].innerHTML = "reverted";
    }
}

setTimeout(setText, 1000);
setTimeout(setText.r, 1000);
```

So, basically the word `some text` and `other text` will change into `new text` after one second. I'm trying to change it into `reverted` one second after that using a method. How can I do that?

Comment: to elaborate you want to change some text to new text then wait for 1 second then change new text to reverted?

Comment: yes, the duration of every word to change to another word is set to 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from our chat this is the way to go.

```js
let x, a, arr, i;

function setText() {
    a = document.getElementById("demo");
    arr = a.childNodes;
    for (x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        arr[x].innerHTML = "new text";
    }
    setTimeout(revert, 1000);
}
function revert() {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i].innerHTML = "reverted";
    }
}

setTimeout(setText, 1000);
setTimeout(setText.r, 1000);
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <div id="demo">
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some other text</p>
    </div>
    <script src="style.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

more simpler:

```js
let x, a, arr, i;

function setText() {
  a = document.getElementById("demo");
  arr = a.childNodes;
  for (x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    arr[x].innerHTML = "new text";
  }
}

function revert() {
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].innerHTML = "reverted";
  }
}

setTimeout(setText, 1000);
setTimeout(revert, 2000);
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="demo">
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some other text</p>
  </div>
  <script src="style.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is working, but how if I want to make the revert as a method? Is that possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.